# How to modify legend in rworldmap package

Tags: r, rworldmap

I am trying to plot a map, color coded by the GDP of the country. The data set is like this

```
Country        GDP
Afghanistan    20315
Armenia        NA
Bahrain        32215
```

This is my code

```
library(rworldmap)
countries = read.csv("countries.csv", na.strings = " NA")

sPDF = joinCountryData2Map(countries, joinCode = "NAME", nameJoinColumn = "Country")
mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot = "GDP", missingCountryCol = "dark grey")
```

[image: And here is the plot]

That is the plot I get. How can I edit the legend? I'd like it to display a scale from lowest to highest, or something similar instead of showing every single value.

Comment: Is `GDP` coded as a factor or character (rather than numeric) by some chance? (Check with `str(countries$GDP)`. If so, convert it to numeric and you should get a numerically scaled legend, rather than individual values. If character, do `countries$GDP = as.numeric(countries$GDP)`; if factor, do `countries$GDP = as.numeric(as.character(countries$GDP))`.

Comment: @eipi10 You're right, for some reason it was coded as a factor. I converted it to numeric and now the legend has completely disappeared.

Comment: Not sure about the error, but did you do `as.numeric(as.character...` or just `as.numeric(...`

Comment: @eipi10 I did as.numeric(as.character(countries$GDP) and it removed the error, but now the plot doesn't have a legend.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data and the exact code that reproduces the problem? That will make it easier to help you. Post a data sample by pasting into your question the output of `dput(head(countries))`.

Comment: @eipi10 The code I've posted above is pretty much the full code. Anyway, I added this to my code 
`mapP = mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot = "GDP", addLegend = FALSE)
do.call(addMapLegend, c(mapP, legendWidth = 0.5, legendMar =2))` 
and it fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great! Glad you were able to solve the problem.